# XSLT concat string

Tags: xslt, string-concatenation

I have the following XML

```
   <R N="14" MIME="application/pdf">
       <RK>7</RK>
       <FS NAME="date" VALUE="2007-11-01" />
       <MT N="Abstract" V="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing " />
       <MT N="Abstract1" V="and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard " />
       <MT N="Abstract2" V="dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley" />
       <MT N="CreationDate" V="D:20070730173554+05'30'" />
       <MT N="Creator" V="PageMaker 6.5" />
       <MT N="Producer" V="Acrobat Distiller 8.0.0 (Windows)" />
       <MT N="ModDate" V="D:20071024091122+05'30'" />
       <S>
           <b>...</b> handling / storage. Operational reactor physics plays an important role in<br/>
           efficient, smooth and safe operation of <b>nuclear reactor</b>. In <b>...</b>
       </S>
       <LANG>en</LANG>
   </R>
```

Using XSLT, I need to concatenate the values of Abstract, Abstract1, Abstract2, Abstract3... so on.

My XSLT is something like this

```
 <xsl:template match="R">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="MT[@N = 'Abstract' and @V != '']">
            <xsl:call-template name="reformat_keyword">
                <xsl:with-param name="orig_string" select="concat(MT[@N='Abstract']/@V,MT[@N='Abstract1']/@V,MT[@N='Abstract2']/@V)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="$show_res_snippet != '0'">
                <xsl:call-template name="reformat_keyword">
                    <xsl:with-param name="orig_string" select="S" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of the static concatenation, I need a generic function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT transformation, string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168867/xslt-transformation-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you can do something like

```
<xsl:variable name="con-cats"><xsl:apply-templates
    select="MT[starts-with(@N,'Abstract')]"
    mode="concatthem"/></xsl:variable>
```

elsewhere:

```
<xsl:template match="MT" mode="concatthem">
 <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*|text()" mode="concatthem" />
```

(not tested, may have errors).

Comment: I reckoned the problem was in how to select nodes where the attribute have a non-constant value...

Comment: thanks.Its close. It concatenates all the strings under MT. I need to selectively concatenate only Abstract, Abstract1, Abstract2.. etc.. Its best, if this can be made generic. Meaning, now it is for Abstract, later may be for Creator1, Creator2 etc..

Comment: Ah. Well, you can select `MT[starts-with(@N,'Abstract')]`, the select part was just an example.

Answer (score 4):

In XSLT 2.0, it's

```
<xsl:variable name="answer" 
    select="string-join(MT[starts-with(@N, 'Abstract']/@V, '')"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, it's

```
<xsl:variable name="answer">
  <xsl:for-each select="MT[starts-with(@N, 'Abstract']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```