# XSLT transformation, string concatenation

Tags: xslt, string-concatenation

I have the below xml

```
<R N="14" MIME="application/pdf">
    <RK>7</RK>
    <MT N="Abstract"
        V="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing " />
    <MT N="Abstract1"
  V="and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard "/>
    <MT N="Author" V="Bernard Shaw;" />
    <MT N="Author1" V="Mark Twain" />
    <MT N="Abstract2"
   V="dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley"/>
    <LANG>en</LANG>
</R>
```

When transforming with an XSLT, I need to concatenate the Abstract and Author fields, and show it like

```
Abstract: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley

Author: Bernard Shaw;Mark Twain
```

The Abstract, Abstract1, Abstract2 may appear in any order in the xml.

I am trying to use something like below, but stuck on the condition & concatenation of string when Abstract, Abstract1 doesn't appear in the same order

```
<xsl:template match="MT">
    <xsl:if test="(some generic condition to display Title)">
        <br/>
        <span class="f">
            <xsl:value-of select="@N"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could give example outputs (what you do see and what you want to see).

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is refactored to be most generic. :)

Comment: Check my answer for a grouping approach just changing the rule matching `MT` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     Abstract: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:for-each select="*/MT[starts-with(@N, 'Abstract')]">
       <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   Author: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:for-each select="*/MT[starts-with(@N, 'Author')]">
       <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<R N="14" MIME="application/pdf">
    <RK>7</RK>
    <MT N="Abstract" V="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing " />
    <MT N="Abstract1" V="and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard " />
    <MT N="Author" V="Bernard Shaw;" />
    <MT N="Author1" V="Mark Twain" />
    <MT N="Abstract2" V="dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley" />
    <LANG>en</LANG>
</R>
```

**produces the wanted result:**

```
Abstract: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
Author: Bernard Shaw;Mark Twain
```

**Further refactoring**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     Abstract: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:call-template name="concatAttributes"/>
   Author: <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:call-template name="concatAttributes">
      <xsl:with-param name="pKeyStartString" select="'Author'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="concatAttributes">
  <xsl:param name="pKeyAttribName" select="'N'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pKeyStartString" select="'Abstract'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pValueAttribName" select="'V'"/>

     <xsl:for-each select=
      "*/MT[starts-with(@*[name()=$pKeyAttribName], $pKeyStartString)]">
       <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$pValueAttribName]"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**A second refactoring (requested by the OP):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vAbstract">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="retrieve" select="//MT"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vAuthors">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="retrieve" select="//MT">
            <xsl:with-param name="pKeyStartString" select="'Author'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     Abstract: <xsl:value-of select="$vAbstract"/>
     Authors:: <xsl:value-of select="$vAuthors"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MT" mode="retrieve">
        <xsl:param name="pKeyAttribName" select="'N'"/>
        <xsl:param name="pKeyStartString" select="'Abstract'"/>
        <xsl:param name="pValueAttribName" select="'V'"/>
        <xsl:if test="starts-with(@*[name()=$pKeyAttribName], $pKeyStartString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$pValueAttribName]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: The OP has requested that "all processing should be done within the template matching `MT`". While this is possible in simple cases (see @Alejandro's answer), doing all the processing in a single template matching `MT` opens big gaps of unknowns. For example, it may be required to process other `MT` elements in a different way and in this case such processing will not be done at all.

In more complex cases (such as when the elements and attributes come in any order, but the output must be sorted -- Abstract1, Abstract2, ..., Abstract-N), then the sort has to be specified explicitly and this has to be outside the template matching `MT`. **Therefore, in the general case, it is not possible to produce the required output with code only within the template matching `MT`.**

**I would recommend that the single template matching `MT` be in a named mode** and that it should be used in "pull style" -- applied explicitly by the caller.

Comment: thanks Dimitre. I am looking for something more generic. Meaning, there could be many other tags like Abstract & Author. All of them would follow the format - name, name1, name2, name3.... Those needs to be displayed as name: value of( name + name1+ .. + nameN)

Comment: @itsbalur: See my refactoring. :)

Comment: @Dimitre, thanks once again. I have one more limitation. The match has to be `<xsl:template match="MT">` , since what I am trying to do is part of a larger XSLT. Could you guide me what needs to be changed for the above code to work with this limitation?

Comment: @itsbalur: This is impossible to achive only inside the template matching `MT`. If you do so, the text `"Abstract: "` will appear N times, but you want it only once.

Comment: @itsbalur: Produced a "second refactoring" which satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @itsbalur: See my final solution. I believe it is better (safer and more resusable) than the solution given by @Alejandro -- please, read the explanations why this is so -- at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Flack: Thanks. Lack of appreciation is not uncommon at SO.

Comment: @Dimitre, many thanks for your answer. It really is a very neat and generic solution. Definitely helps to address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="MT[starts-with(@N, 'Abstract')]">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="@N"/>:
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kMtByAlphaN"
             match="MT"
             use="concat(generate-id(..),'+',translate(@N,'1234567890',''))"/>
    <xsl:template match="MT[count(.|key('kMtByAlphaN',
                                        concat(
                                           generate-id(..),'+',
                                           translate(@N,'1234567890','')
                                        )
                                    )[1]
                            ) = 1
                         ]">
        <xsl:variable name="vName"
                      select="translate(@N,'1234567890','')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($vName,': ')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kMtByAlphaN',
                                             concat(generate-id(..),'+',$vName)
                                     )/@V"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Abstract: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
Author: Bernard Shaw;Mark Twain
```

**Note**: Grouping by @N alphabetic content and parent generated id because I would expect several `R` elements.